# Prepare solution of salt in ethanol

Tags: spectroscopy

The test for anions can be done with a platinum wire and a Bunsen flame.

My textbook says that it can also be done by preparing a solution of the given salt in water and ethanol and spraying it onto the Bunsen flame.

How do I prepare this solution in terms of how much water, ethanol and salt ?

Comment: Are you sure about anions ?

Comment: Ethanol-based hand sanitizer is readily available, so add a dash of salt, spritz it into a flame and behold the beautiful sodium D lines around 590 nm (yellow). Or just use cheap vodka and add the salt. Or add a little water to ethanol and add the salt. This is one experiment that is guaranteed to work.

Comment: You don't even need the alcohol... almost anything with sodium, whether salt, salt water, or MSG from the kitchen, displays the bright sodium spectral lines when put in a flame.